# Add border to an image with transparent background in Python Pillow Library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working with this image, which has a transparent background. [image]

If I use the following code:-

```
def add_border(input_image, output_image, border, color=0):
    img = Image.open(input_image)
    if isinstance(border, int) or isinstance(border, tuple):
        bimg = ImageOps.expand(img, border=border, fill=color)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Border is not an integer or tuple!')
    bimg.save(output_image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_img = 'input/udit.png'
    add_border(in_img, output_image='udit_border.png',
               border=100, color="red")
```

This adds the border to the frame of the image.

I can find clear edges using the following code:-

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageFilter
in_img = Image.open('input/udit.png')
image_with_edges = in_img.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
```

[image]

I was wondering, if I could draw a border across this edge and then join the two images to have a border on my image. But I couldn't find a way to do that. I want to change it into a sticker, so I am looking for something like the following image without bg.

[image]

Comment: Can you show expected image?

Comment: @Alderven I have updated my question with the expected pic. I want to convert the pic into a sticker so I am looking to add the border.